Bash command substitution issues
I'm writing a Python script to parse various logs across different hosts.
I can successfully run bash scripts via Python's subprocess module, however, I want to minimize the number of ssh calls, so I'm trying to combine ssh, grep, and find into 1 command.
The problem begins when some hosts may not have any log files. My command is something like:
ssh SOME_HOST 'grep "SOME_VALUE" $(find SOME_PATH -type f -name "*.log")'

When there are no log files, this becomes grep "SOME_VALUE" and hangs forever. I tried wrapping it in double quotes so that it becomes grep "SOME_VALUE" "" instead:
ssh SOME_HOST 'grep "SOME_VALUE" "$(find SOME_PATH -type f -name "*.log")"'

Now I have the exact opposite problem: when there are some logs found, I get:
grep: FILE_A^JFILE_B^J... : No such file or directory

I've been stuck on this for a few days and googling / RTFMing hasn't helped much. I have tried tr to replace newlines with spaces but got some other weird errors :( Is there an easy way to do this in one command?

You'd have the same problem if you were doing this locally, without ssh.

Add an extra filename argument so the argument list is never empty. You can use /dev/null as a dummy file that never matches grep.
ssh SOME_HOST 'grep "SOME_VALUE" $(find SOME_PATH -type f -name "*.log") /dev/null'



unfortunately exec and xargs are disabled on the machines due to security policies

Add an extra /dev/null filename argument.

I wasn't aware of this trick, it works! thanks.

It's also an old trick that we used to use before the -H option was added to grep, so we'd get filenames even if only one file matches the wildcard.
